# MVC Upload File Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Thanks for your time. Before I begin I would like to show you my code.

Model

```
public class Files
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Picture { get; set; } 
}
```

View

```
@model FileUpload.Models.Picture
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFileTest", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =  "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="Picture" id="Picture" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

FileUploadController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFileTest(Picture file)
{
    if (file.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.File.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), fileName);
        file.File.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("UploadFileTest");
}
```

After I upload the file and click submit, I received this error message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at `if (file.FileFile.ContentLength > 0)`

Comment: Your file is named `Picture`, not `file`! Change the input to `<input type="file" name="File"  />`, or better, strongly bind to your model using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke HI Stephen. Ill give it a try thanks again :#

Comment: @StephenMuecke Still got the same errors :<

Comment: Your model does not make sense in relationship to your controller code. Is it actually `public class Picture { public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; } }`? And if it is, then you need to change the name of the parameter in the POST method to (say) `public ActionResult UploadFileTest(Picture model)` (the name of the parameter cannot be the same as the name of a property in the model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `FileUploadController` like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFileTest(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.File.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), fileName);
        file.File.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("UploadFileTest");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works. Its just that I am wondering why mine in the previous code is not working.

Comment: That cannot possibly work, since the name of the input is `Picture`, not `file`!